# How to extract the tendency of lectors

Tags: google-sheets-api

We use a lot of google sheets to create our reports, and there is an option to see which people of the company have acceded and at which time to open and view the doc.

Is there an option to extract a report of this information directly or by API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Drive activity can be accessed with the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2).
- Consequently you use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started) to access [Drive Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive).

> Mind that as specified [here](G Suite Business customers) this feature
>   is only available for G Suite Business customers.